# How to make a circular clipping mask on an image which will work with IE9?

Tags: html, css, less

The code i'm using right now is this:
**(Note that this is formatted in css less.)**
It doesn't seem to work with IE9 or older and after looking into it i can't find the right formatting for it.

```
.mixin-clip-path-circle(@1,@2,@3) {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(@1, @2, @3); 
  -moz-clip-path: circle(@1, @2, @3);
  clip-path: circle(@1, @2, @3);
}

.user-portrait {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  .clipped-portrait {
    .mixin-clip-path-circle(3.4rem, 3.4rem, 3.4rem);
    min-height: 6.8rem;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
  }

<div class="user-portrait">
     <img src="img/styleguide/portrait-picture-example.png" class="clipped-portrait" />
</div>
```

EDIT: To be clear, i'm looking for a way to make this work in IE9, it doesn't have to be with the clip-path property.

Comment: Have you tried `border-radius`?

Answer (score 0):

MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) seems to indicate that `clip-path` is only supported in IE9+.